# Reverse multiple words in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I have the following list and would like to reverse the order of the words not each letter in the word. I currently have this but its reversing each letter and not the order of the words.

JS:

```
let items = ["Litte Bike, Tall Tree, Toy Car, Fast Car"].toString();
myArray.split("").reverse().join('')
```

Current output:

```
raC tsaF ,raC yoT ,eerT llaT ,ekiB ettiL
```

Desired output:

```
Bike Litte 
Tree Tall 
Car Toy 
Car Fast
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to split by the comma first, then split on each word in the new array of items and reverse those.

You don't want to reverse the whole thing.

```js
let items = ["Litte Bike, Tall Tree, Toy Car, Fast Car"].toString();

let result = items.split(',').map(item => item.split(' ').reverse().join(' ').trim());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let items = ["Litte Bike, Tall Tree, Toy Car, Fast Car"];


let revItems = items.map(item => item.split(" ").reverse().join(" "));

console.log(revItems.reverse())
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you have to split up the elements first, then the individual spaces in each element, and print in reverse.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            p {
                margin: 0px !important;
                padding: 0px !important;
                border: 0px !important;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function foo() {
                let items = ["Litte Bike,Tall Tree,Toy Car,Fast Car"].toString().replace(', ',','); //replace the spaces in the string between separations
                var myarray = items.split(','); //separate all the individual items 
                for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) { //for each item, split on the space in between words
                    var subArray = myarray[i].split(" "); 
                    //i ignore errors
                    console.log(subArray[1] + " " + subArray[0]); //print the order reversed.
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="foo();">

    </body>
    </html>
```